# Как указать адрес ссылки?

Tags: php, html

Пользуюсь хостингом 000h.tk. При редактировании сайта, к примеру, указывал ссылку http://dbmn-sc.ml/my_photos/flat.jpg на фон для сайта, однако открывая при этом страницу, которую я редактировал, изображение не показывалось (знак вопроса вместо изображения). Конечно, можно подумать, что я указывал неверную ссылку, однако ссылку, которую я прописывал на странице копировал и вставлял в URL-строку. Всё работает. Не работает только в странице. Страница, которую я редактирую и картинка, которую я хочу вставить на страницу хранятся на одном и том же хостинге - 000h.tk. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А что мешает скопировать картинку и положить ее на свой хостинг? С чужого ее в любой момент могут удалить, и останетесь без фона.

Comment: Чтобы работало на странице, вы обертывали ссылку в тег <img> (<img src="http://dbmn-sc.ml/my_photos/flat.jpg")?

Comment: Да. Но не в этом дело. Вроде так происходит не только с ссылками на изображение, но и с ссылками на какие-либо другие файлы на хостинге 000h.tk. Если я ставлю ссылку http://dbmn-sc.ml/my_photos/flat.jpg на странице другого хостинга - всё нормально.